# How to integrate Drewm package for mailchimp in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

We have installed the drewm in `vendor/drewm/` using composer.

We have defined it in  aliases also 
   `'MailChimp' => drewm\mailchimp-api\src\MailChimp::class`,
including it in controller using following.

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
use Mailchimp;
```

But when we are trying to create object

```
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('71b4b2d2cfab34ba16e6054afef0df10');
```

we are getting the following error:

```
Class "DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp' not found" and another error "Mailchmp is already in use"
```

Help is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wouldn't use both use entries.`use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;` should be enough;
Also remove the alias, alias are used mostly for static/facade classes.